How to get OpenAI response as JSON object using NextJS Vercel AI
I'm trying to get the response as a JSON object then use the data to display its value:
Example:
{
  name: Dr.Seuss,
  food: green eggs and ham
}

Wanted Result:
"My name is Dr.Seuss and I like green eggs and ham"

NextJS + Typescript
import OpenAI from 'openai';
import { OpenAIStream, StreamingTextResponse, StreamData } from 'ai';
 
// Create an OpenAI API client
const openai = new OpenAI({
  apiKey: process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY,
});
 
export const dynamic = 'force-dynamic';
 
export async function POST(req: Request) {
  // Extract the `prompt` from the body of the request
  const { prompt } = await req.json();
 
  // Ask OpenAI for a streaming completion given the prompt
  const response = await openai.chat.completions.create({
    model: 'gpt-3.5-turbo',
    max_tokens: 256,
    stream: true,
    messages: [
      {
        role: 'user',
        content:  `give me a list of name and their favorite food in JSON object. \n`,
      },
    ],
  });
 
    // Instantiate the StreamData. It works with all API providers.

  // Convert the response into a friendly text-stream
  const stream = OpenAIStream(response);
  // Respond with the stream
  return new StreamingTextResponse(stream);
}


I've search various sources for hours (docs, articles, YT videos) and haven't found a solution yet.
Any help will be appreciated.
